# Why isn't "Puto deus fio" grammatically incorrect?

Tags: classical-latin, subordinate-clause, suetonius, oratio-obliqua

According to Suetonius, the final words of emperor Vespasian were "Vae! Puto deus fio" which translates to "Alas! I think I'm becoming a god".

But the 'proper' way of saying this would be using an acc-inf construction, i.e. "Vae! Puto me deum fieri". Why did he say it the other way? I've never seen this construction before, and I've always been told the acc-inf is the right way of doing it. Is this a later Latin construction which became acceptable to use?

Comment: Keep in mind that spoken Latin and written Latin had diverged even before the Empire, and what someone *says* might not be the same as what someone might *write*. (That said, I have no idea if the acc-inf would be specific to the written form, but I suppose it is possible.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In this case I would read *puto* more as a side remark to the clause *deus fio*.
You could emphasize this with punctuation:

> *Puto: deus fio.*
>   I think: I'm becoming a god.

The verb *puto* is indeed grammatically detached from the rest of the clause.
It is grammatically correct, but it is not really grammatically connected to *deus fio*.
(The semantic connection is strong, of course.)
It would also be grammatical to say *puto me deum fieri*, but that would give a somewhat different tone.

The word *credo* is often used in a similar fashion, essentially as an interjection.
For example, consider this quote from [Cicero, *Pro S. Roscio Amerino* 76.7–8](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/474/2/17/434-439@1#17):

> *Litteras, credo, misit alicui sicario qui Romae noverat neminem.*
>   He sent letters, I think, to an assassin who knew no one in Rome.

Compare this to "I think that he sent letters..." to see the difference between *puto* as an "interjection" and with an ACI.

I don't know if this became more common in later Latin, but the construction does exist in classical authors like Cicero and it seems very common in Plautus.

Answer (score 3):

As Joonas noted, *puto* is parenthetical. I'll just add, by way of comparison, that Claudius's *ultima vox* in Seneca's *Apocolocyntosis* was 'vae me, puto, concacavi me.'

Answer (score 0):

The actual quotation in Suetonius Vesp. 23 is "“ut puto, deus fio,” "As I surmise, I am becoming a god". "Ut puto" is a subordinate clause.

Comment: I looked it up myself in the most recent, authoritative and critical edition by Robert Kaster (2016), in the OCT series. He traces the reading with "ut" to a fifteenth century manuscript (Toledo) and **he clearly marks ut false reading**.

Comment: I was lazy and copied it out of L/S. Proves you should never trust a dictionary. @AlexB.

Comment: No problem - I guess I should say something like, Quandoque bonus dormitat Homerus.